# will running multiple sed substitution to one file in parallel cause safety issue?

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following code:

```
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    echo "start mask $file with ${#mask_words_in_array[@]} words"
    # Loop through each word in the array
    for mask_word in "${mask_words_in_array[@]}"; do
        for i in $(seq 1 40)
        do
            # Replace the mask_word with asterisks of equal length
            sed -i "s|$mask_word|$(printf '*%.0s' $(seq 1 ${#mask_word}))|g" "$file" &
        done
        wait
    done
 fi
```

Starting 40 processes to substitute the same file using sed, I'm
wondering will it cause any data safety issues?
Like file got overridden by `sed` or file corruption,
and if this is safe way to substitute,
is there a reasonable way to determine how many process I should be using?

update:
thanks guys, i decided not to use bash to address the problem, beside the process safe issue,sed did perform as well as i imagine(i have maybe millions lines of logs to mask) , it took 5 mins to finish a 0.2 millions lines of logs, probably not the right tool to swing at this scenario, need to find a faster tool for this.
i should close this question,but don't know how just new to stackoverflow, LOL

Comment: This is a nice way to spoil your file. Prefer a sequential run. If you have performance issues, consider a single `sed` run for all your substitutions, it will be much faster than the sequential run. Use your existing code to generate a single `sed` script. And call `sed` only once.

Comment: It looks to me like all 40 instances of `sed` are doing exactly the same substitution. Is there any actual reason for this? If there is -- that is, if there were actually 40 *different* substitutions to be made, the most likely result is that you'll get a final file with only one of them done. But that's only one possibility; depending on timing, there are lots of other things (pretty much all bad) that might happen.

Comment: I just tested this, using 40 distinct substitutions (on a big file, so that all 40 instances could start before any had a chance to finish), and as I expected I got a result with only one substitution done (it was #31 on the first test, #25 on the second). On the second test, I used `-i.bkp` to create a backup of the "original" file, and the backup turned out to have substitution #6 in it.

Comment: As you do not use variable `i` in your `for i in $(seq 1 40)` loop what is the point of this loop?

Comment: If the words to mask contain regex meta-characters (`.`, `*`,...) your substitutions will probably go wrong. You will mask words that shouldn't be masked and not mask words that should be.

Comment: Also, why did you tag the question _bash_  and _sh_? Please make up your mind, which of those languages you want to use.

Comment: thanks, i decide not to use bash to address the problem, obviously ,it's not the right tool to swing at this scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will it cause any data safety issues?

Yes, the data may be corrupted. You can't read and write to the same file at the same time and expect sane results.

> how many process I should be using?

I propose, one file, one sed. It's very very easy to convert your code to a single sed call - just generate the single sed script.

```
   script=""
   for mask_word in "${mask_words_in_array[@]}"; do
        for i in $(seq 1 40)
        do
            # Replace the mask_word with asterisks of equal length
            script+="s|$mask_word|$(printf '*%.0s' $(seq 1 ${#mask_word}))|g;"
        done
    done
    sed -i "$script" "$file"
```

If you want to parse data in parallel and preserve consistency, then you built pipelines `intput | do this | do that | output > tmpefile; mv tempfile input`. I.e. do not work on a *file*, but work on a *stream* of data. Save data to a temporary file and mv it to input if you want to modify after done. Note that `sed -i` *does that* - created a temporary file and moves it. Also see `sponge` from moreutils.

Comment: Isn't that still O(n) `s///`s running in series? I interpreted the question as trying to run the `s///` in parallel.

Comment: If you don't needlessly rewrite the same file once per pattern, the performance problems and thus the need to parallelize will probably disappear as if through magic.

Answer (score 1):

If you do more than precisely one substitution at a time, you create a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) where some changes will probably be lost.

Implementing the [standard protections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem) in your code is non-trivial. You would want line-level [locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking), which sed does not support. (With a whole-file lock, you would just be serialising the entire procedure, and lose all parallelisation.)

For your case, there is a workaround: combine all the substitutions into one check, so that no parallelisation is required.

However, as comments mention, you may find that reducing file I/O provides more benefit than trying to parallelise or combine the regex. For example, although the Perl code I show below runs effectively independently of the number of masks provided, it only becomes faster than a naive sed implementation when there are several hundred masks. So, if you only have 40 masks, instead of:

```
sed -i 's/mask1/*****/g' file
sed -i 's/mask2/*****/g' file
# ...
sed -i 's/mask40/******/g' file
```

you may see a significant performance boost just by changing to:

```
sed -i '
    s/mask1/*****/g
    s/mask2/*****/g
    # ...
    s/mask40/******/g
' file
```

KamilCuk's answer suggests a way to generate such a script from your mask array (but note that it does not escape sed metacharacters from the masks), or you can try something like:

```
printf '%s\n' "${mask_words_in_array[*]}" |
sed '
    # make asterisk version
    h
    s/./*/g
    x

    # escape metacharacters
    # cf. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129063
    s:[][\\/.^$*]:\\&:g

    # combine into s///g command
    G
    s/\n/|/
    s/^/s|/
    s/$/|g/
' | sed -f - -i file
```

---

Note that your current code logic has other problems that will need thought:

1. If two or more masks overlap, not all may be applied.

Consider masks `abc` and `cde` and text `abcde`.

It could be that the expected result is `*****`.
However because of the overlap, actual result might be `***de` or `ab***`.

2. The masks are not delimited, so some text may be masked that should not.

This is similar to the [Scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem). In that case, attempting to filter rude words may result in innocent text being blocked.

---

Here is a sample bash/Perl implementation that checks for all masks at once:

```
if [[ -f $file ]]; then
    # create single newline-delimited string to pass to perl
    # assumes newlines do not appear in the masks
    export masklist=$(IFS=$'\n'; echo "${mask_words_in_array[*]}")

    perl -i.bak -p -e '
        BEGIN {
            ($re) = map qr/$_/,
                    join "|",
                    map {
                        $star{$_} = y//*/cr;
                        "\Q$_\E"
                    }
                    split /\n/,
                    $ENV{masklist}
        }
        s/($re)/$star{$1}/g
    ' "$file"
fi
```

First create regex variable (`$re`) and substitution mapping hash (`%star`):

- `$ENV{masklist}` is the string passed in
- `split` converts it back into a list
- `map` takes each list element (`$_`) and

  - creates an all-asterisks version (`y//*/cr`) which is assigned to hash element (`$star{$_}`)
  - wraps it (`"\Q$_\E"`) to disable recognition of pattern metacharacters later
- `join` all the strings with pattern metacharacter (`|`)
- `map qr/$_/` compiles the combined string to a regex
- finally assign to `$re` for later use

Then backup the file (`-i.bak`) and update each line after manipulation (`-p`).

The manipulation is a global search & replace (`s/.../.../g`): look for a regex match for any of the strings, then replace by the appropriate mapped value.

Comment: Why the switch to Perl, though? This would not be hard to write in `sed` either.

Comment: @tripleee mainly because I find `"\Q$dangerous\E"` easier to remember than looking up something like [`escaped_lhs=$(printf '%s\n' "$lhs" | sed 's:[][\\/.^$*]:\\&:g')`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129063/333919)

Comment: @tripleee most of the work here happens in perl. With sed, I think most of it would have to be done in bash itself. Also, I don't know how to use one regex and get multiple replacements in sed.

Comment: In brief, `printf 's%s\n' "${mask_words_in_array[@]}" | sed -e 's%.*%s|&|&|%' -e:a -e 's/[^*]\([*]*|\)$/*\1/' -e ta | sed -f - -i targetfile` but I haven't tested this.

Comment: @tripleee If I understood your code, I think your first `s///` is missing a `g` and the second has a termination problem but the main thing is that it's still multiple `s///` being tested in series, not a single test. Also, doesn't check for sed metacharacters in the input.

Comment: You don't need or want a `g` when there can only be a single match per line. Yes, this ad-hoc code could certainly use some robustness fixes. Maybe sort the input file by length to make sure longer patterns take precedence over shorter ones? But the OP's requirements are obviously rather fuzzy.

Comment: @tripleee I meant for the output: `s%.*%s|&|&|g%`. By termination, 2nd `s` overwrites everything, not just RHS. Perhaps `sed 'h; s/./*/g; x; s:[][\\/.^$*]:\\&:g; G; s/\n/|/; s/^/s|/; s/$/|g/'` but ignoring the `seq 1 40` issue, KamilCuk's bash is probably clearer.

Comment: @triplee I just tried a benchmark. Perl does seem to take constant time regardless of number of masks, but it ran much more slowly than the naive multi-`s///` sed (32s vs 0.22/0.27/0.46/0.80/1.45 for 1/2/4/8/16 masks). So not a win if you don't have a lot of masks.. I'll update my answer.